# The contents of my XML document does not load into the HTML Element

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I tried to get the contents of the XML document and add it to my div element with the ID GameReview.

```js
function getXML() //this is meant to retrieve the xml document.
{
    var xmlrequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

 xmlrequest.onreadystatechange =
  function()
  {
   if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200)
    {
     populateDIV(this);
    }
  };

 xmlrequest.open("GET", "finalfantasy.xml", true);
 xmlrequest.send();
}
 
    function populateDIV(xml)
    {
  var finalfantasyReview = xml.responseXML;
  var start;
  var x = finalfantasyReview.getElementsByTagName("REVIEW");
  start="<h2>"+x[0].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</h2>" +
       
     "<h3>"+x[0].getElementsByTagName("OVERVIEW")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</h3>" +
     "<p>"+x[0].getElementsByTagName("CONTENT")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +"</p>";
  document.getElementById("GameReview").innerHtml = "";
  document.getElementById("GameReview").innerHtml = start;
 }
Below is my HTML the Elements in the div GameReview the contents should be replaced with the XML contents.
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleSheet.css">
 <title> Logi's Blog</title> 
 

</head>

<body>
 <h1> Logi's Blog</h1>
<div id="nav">
 <ul class="TopMenuContainer">
  <li class="TopMenuList"><a href="">Games</a></li>
  <li class="TopMenuList"><a href="">Cartoons</a></li>
  <li class="TopMenuList"><a href="">TV Shows</a></li>
  <li class="TopMenuList"><a href="">Anime</a></li>
 </ul>
</div> 
<h2 class="GamesTitle">Games</h2>
<div id="Container">
 <div class="GamesListContainer">
  <ul>
   <li><button type="button" onclick="getXML()">Final Fantasy</button></li>
   <li>Rachet and Clank</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="GameReview">
  <h2>Game</h2>
  <img src="images/getting_started_with_content_strategy.jpg" alt="content strategy" style="width:356px;height:200px;"/>
  <h3>Overview<h3>
  <p>This is where all the great content goes when you click on a review.</P>
  <p id="GamePoopReview"></p>
 </div>
<
</body>
<html>
```

I'm unsure as to what i did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The last two lines in my function PopulateDIV(xml) I had Forgotten to capitalise "HTML" in the object .innerHTML.